# D3.js keyboard controls (tab)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to navigate the D3 collapsible trees using TAB? So tabbing to each node and hitting enter to expand. Just thinking about accessibility.

At the moment TAB just highlights the Canvas.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add this functionality manually. That is, create an event listener for TAB and in it mark a particular node as "active". Similar for Enter to expand. So the answer to your question is "yes", but it would not be entirely straightforward.